# Confusion Regarding Gazebo 4 and ROS Installation

Tags: gazebo-4, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been trying to install Gazebo 4 along with ROS Indigo in the following method:

```
    1. Install ros-indigo-desktop-full
    2. Run sudo apt-get remove gazebo-* (I realized that it also removes ROS)
    3. Following along the source installation instructions for Gazebo 4 on this page (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install), which resulted in a problem related to this question (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7224/gazebo-4-installation-fails-on-make-j4/)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? An answer I got from a different question here (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7008/gazebo-4-installation-help/) yielded a different way to install Gazebo 4 along side ROS Indigo. Am I supposed to just do a desktop install and not a full install? Or would the Gazebo 4 packages automatically override the Gazebo 2 ones that came with Indigo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7234/confusion-regarding-gazebo-4-and-ros-installation/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I recommend [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros), which describes how to use different combinations of ROS and Gazebo versions. Short answer: install `ros-indigo-gazebo4-ros-pkgs` to use gazebo4 with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-22**:
Thank you, I'll try to follow along with it. Should I install the full desktop version of ROS (that includes Gazebo 2), then? Or should I go for the plain desktop version (with rqt, rviz, and robot-generic libraries and no Gazebo)?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-22**:
Also, should I install ROS first or Gazebo first. I noticed that when I installed ros-indigo-gazebo4-ros-pkgs, ros-indigo-desktop-full was automatically removed.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-22**:
You can install `ros-indigo-desktop-full` first and then `ros-indigo-gazebo4-ros-pkgs` and it will leave any packages that aren't in conflict

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-22**:
It works now! Thank you very much.